# Waiting for Controls to be Initialized

Tags: c#, winforms

My form looks something like a three-pane email client.  Left side is a grid with a list of people.  Top right is the current person's detail record.  Bottom right is a custom control with many checkboxes displaying the current person's areas of expertise:

> [x] cooking  [x] window cleaning [x] brain surgery
>
> [x] massage-therapy [x] singing  [ ] random acts of vandalism

When the form is opened, the focus goes to the first person listed in the grid on the left-side of the form,, and the grid's focused_row_changed event fires. In the handler for this event I get the current person's id, then fetch detail data for that person from the database and populate the detail record, and also fetch the person's areas-of-expertise rows and set the checkboxes. All of this is working fine except when the form is first opened, because then the custom control with its many checkboxes is not yet initialized. At that point MyCustomControl is null.

```
if (null != MyCustomControl)
{
  MyCustomControl.SetCheckedValues( datasource);
}
```

What is the best practice design-pattern for handling this situation? What do I do here when my control isn't fully initialized yet?

```
if (null != MyCustomControl)
{
  MyCustomControl.SetCheckedValues( datasource);
} 
else 
{
  // ?? Wait around for a bit and keep trying every 100ms?
}
```

Comment: Can you go into a little more detail about when MyCustomControl becomes initialized and what its initialization depends on?

Answer (score 1):

The way I have solved this in my controls when they have had this problem is to implement [ISupportInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize.aspx).

In your control, you would put something like:

```
public class MyCustomControl: ISupportInitialize
{
    private bool _initializing = false;

    private void BeginInit()
    {
        _initializing = true;
    }

    private void EndInit()
    {
        _initializing = false;
    }

    private void SomeMethodThatWouldRaiseAnEventDuringInit()
    {
        if (_initializing) return;
        //...
    }
}
```

The windows forms designer checks for your control implementing the interface, and produces this code in the `.Designer.cs` file:

```
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.customControl1)).BeginInit();
///
/// customControl1
///
this.customControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;  //this would normally raise the event
((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.customControl1)).EndInit();
```

Comment: does this go into the quick control or the slowpoke control? I'm not sure how it would work.  My slowpoke control simply displays some data that is sent to it, but the control that fetches the data from the database is initialized and populated faster than the control that will display the data. Is there a way to delay the initialization of the faster control until after the slowpoke control has finished initializing?

Answer (score 0):

Do your UI initialization functions in a subroutine that isn't called until after all the other UI elements are initialized, or base your calculations on the back-end values instead of the UI.

---

in response to comments and other posts, if you can't get anything else to work, you can add a 'refresh' button to the UI

Comment: The grid that contains a list people fires a focused-row-changed event whenever focus moves from row to row. That is the UI that the user interacts with and the person-detail-record and person-expertise-records must be fetched whenever the user selects a different person. I have no control over when that grid is finished initializing.

Comment: I am hoping to avoid the Refresh button because it requires the user to know that the data needs to be refreshed and to take action. Ideally I'd like to find a way to have the fast control wake up only after the slow control has woken up. I want the earlybird control to stay in bed and want the sleepyhead control to wake up and say "Rise and shine!" to the earlybird control. I suppose the sleepyhead control could add the earlybird control to the form's controls list in the sleepyhead's InitializationComplete event.

Comment: re: What do I do here when my control isn't fully initialized yet?  you have to wait until it is fully initialized, then refresh.  Can your slow control notify your fast control when it's done?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are setting `MyCustomControl.SetCheckedValues( datasource);` when focused_row_changed event fires.

This also tends to happen when the form is just loading, which is generally not desired, because you end up with events telling things to load when, for example, a selected index is still -1.

The way I have been working around this is I have a global boolean in the form called `doneLoading`.  It starts off false and becomes true when the Form_Shown() event gets called.

From there I just put an `if(doneLoading)` around any piece of code that needs to wait until the form is actually done loading before it is allowed to execute.  In your case, I would do:

```
if(doneLoading)
{
MyCustomControl.SetCheckedValues( datasource);
}
```

Comment: In the Form_Shown() event I would then have to manually set the focus in the Persons grid to the first row. But focus would already be at the first row, and thus the focused-row-changed event would not fire. So then I'd have to manually launch the routines that fetch the person-detail-record and person-expertise-record, and before you know it, it's no longer an event-driven program but some combination of event-driven coding and good old-timey structured coding. That's what I'm trying to avoid, though maybe it's not possible to avoid it.

Comment: @Tim -- I'm not sure I understand the problem or perhaps the desired behavior.  When the form first opens, do you want MyCustomControl to be populated or do you want to wait until the user has intentionally selected a person?  If it is the latter, then that is what my answer will facilitate.  What the code in my answer does is it suppresses calling your SetCheckedValues() method until after the form is done loading.  To put it another way, you just put the code I put up there in whatever event you had before, and it should only change the overall behavior *prior to* the form loading fully.

Comment: when the form is loaded, the controller list is populated with people names and ids, and focus is set (automatically) to the first row which causes its Focused_Row_Changed event to fire. In the handler for that event I get the focused person's id and fetch detail data from the database. But another control on the form is not yet ready to receive that data. My controller list is faster initializing than a control that receives data from it. At present, my handler keeps knocking at the door of the slowpoke control until it answers the door, so to speak: "Data delivery for Mr. Control!"

Comment: @Tim, without knowing what's actually going on with this other control, why can't you just have that control fire an event when it is done initializing and then the events' handler sets the controller list to the first row (only the first time)?  That way the slowpoke control hands the controller list its data the first time and from then on, the (already initialized) slowpoke control takes its orders from the Focused_Row_Changed event.  Am I sort of getting the gist of your program correctly or am I still way off?

Comment: you've got the gist. In the controller's Focused_Row_Changed eventhandler, I can check to see if the slowpoke control is ready to receive data and send it data only if so. In that handler I can also keep testing to see if the slowpoke control is awake yet, by using a timer. Evert 100 ms I can see if the slowpoke is still null or initializing, or I can test a global variable periodically which would be set by the slowpoke control when it wakes up. I can also have the slowpoke control set the controllers row focus when the slowpoke wakes up. That's another way, though maybe no cleaner.